# Is it possible to generate on the fly SSL certificates from a root CA in C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core

I'm setting up a server under my own root CA to generate SSL certificates on the fly under .NET Core.

I'm able to generate self-signed certificates using the `CertificateRequest` class. However, these certs obviously aren't trusted by clients with my own root CA. I'm using the `CertificateRequest.CreateSelfSigned()` method to do this. I cannot use my root CA to sign these new certs, however. Using the `CertificateRequest.Create()` method will generate my new cert, but it will not provide a private key.

```cs
public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificate(string domain)
{
    SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
    sanBuilder.AddDnsName(domain);

    X500DistinguishedName distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN=On-The-Fly Generated Cert");

    using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        var request = new CertificateRequest(distinguishedName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));


        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));

        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

        var ca = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\testing_ca_certificate.pfx"), "password"); //Open my root CA cert, generated in OpenSSL

        //Generates a cert, but does not provide a private key.
        var certificate = request.Create(ca, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(365)), new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }); 

        //Generates a usable cert, but is not under my root CA
        //var certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(365)));

        return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "password"), "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
    }

}
```

Using the `CertificateRequest.Create()` method, I get a valid cert without a private key. I should have this private key so I can encrypt SSL traffic.

Answer (score 4):

> Using the `CertificateRequest.Create()` method, I get a valid cert without a private key.

Real certificate authorities should not have the private key of the CA and the private key matching the certificate to be created in the same place at the same time.  Aside from the fact that there is currently no way to decode a Certification Request (CSR), this method assumes it's being used with a public-only key provided to the CertificateRequest constructor.

Following the flow, the "expected" model is:

- Client determines the need for a new certificate
- Client generates public/private keypair
- Client sends public key and other necessary information to CA (PKCS#10 CertificationRequest, or other means)
- CA validates request
- CA builds up the `CertificateRequest` object using the client public key
- CA produces a certfificate with `CertificateRequest.Create()`
- CA sends the certificate back to the client (`cert.RawData`)
- Client instantiates `X509Certificate2` instance (only has public key)
- Client uses the `CopyWithPrivateKey` (extension) method to associate the private key to a new certificate object.
- Client does whatever client wants now.

So, after

```
//Generates a cert, but does not provide a private key.
var certificate = request.Create(ca, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(365)), new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
```

you should add

```
certificate = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
```

(Though, really, you should have your certificate objects in `using` statements so they get disposed when no longer needed, in which case you'd need a second variable to hold the cert-with-key)

Answer (score 0):

Given the certificate request was created using your `rsa` instance, you should be able to export the private key from it. [`RSA.ToXmlString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_RSA_ToXmlString_System_Boolean_) allows for exporting the key to a format that later that can be later imported using `RSA.FromXmlString()`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help. ``RSA.ToXmlString()`` and ``RSA.FromXmlString()`` doesn't seem to work in .NET Core and throws a ``Operation is not supported on this platform`` error. More info in [this issue submitted to GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/874).

Comment: @RomanPort [`RSA.ExportParameters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.exportparameters?view=netcore-2.2) should still work for .NET Core